# Pass xml data to a URL from Windows Form opened by a new browser

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a problem on my current project (Windows Form) which needs to pass xml data to a URL opened by a new web browser. Can anybody give me some clues? I had a search online and got 2 possible ways.

1. use HttpWebRequest to send xml data in stream and create URL. but how can you do 'open new browser' in this way?
2. use Process.Start or ProcessInfo.Start. you can specify data in URL parameters. but how can you pass xml data?

Thanks

Comment: why you want to open new browser? you need Response after sending xml?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The xml data will be processed on the URL with additional data added after sending and Page.Request and Page.Response will be also used after sending.

Comment: Note that there is a size limit for data passed via QueryString. Look at using the WebClient class and POSTing the XML (though, in that case, XML is probably overkill and you should just pass everything as Form values.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this with the destination URL for the new browser window being on your own site or on an external site? Do you need something that works for all browsers and not just Internet Explorer? From the nature of your question, I'll start with the assumptions that you are probably trying to pass values to an external site (open in a new window) and that you want to support as many browsers as possible and not rely on IE alone (just good practice to be in). Then really your only option it to pass the XML as part of the QueryString portion of the URL - that is the name=value pairs which exist after the question mark in the URL. When doing this, you need to make sure that the VALUE portion of the name=value pairs in the URL that you are building is properly URL Encoded. Otherwise if you do not use URL Encoding on the value portion, the data will not be parsed correctly by the receiving site. See the following article for info on URL Encoding:

[URL Encode in dot NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

This one thing you need to be careful of if passing XML formatted data (or any large strings of data) via URL based name=value parameters is that the size of the URL might be limited depending on browser and version used. So if you are passing this to another website that is already using this technique, then I'm assuming it is already a functional site and you are not passing a lot of data in the URL for each request.

If your needs are different than these assumptions, please elaborate in more detail and might be able to provide you further/better options.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. The data will pass to external site and can just use IE for less all-browsers works. The xml data has almost 100 keys to pass via https. Will the querystring of the url be efficient solution or cause massive xml manipulation works involved? After the sending over, more data will be added into the xml and waiting for further process at external site. The ideal way for me is to pass the data and open the IE in same time.

Answer (score 0):

No need to open new browser to send and receive data. You can send XML using `HttpWebRequest  POST` method and read the response using `HttpWebResponse`.

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

private string SendRequest(string xml, string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default);
    string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    res.Close();
    return response; 
}
```

Comment: The xml data sent to external site will be waiting for more fields filled by online users. That's why I need to open a new window for further online process. Is there anyway to send data across and pre-populate it on the page which open in new browser?

Comment: what is your server? web service or asp.net web site?

Comment: Sorry didn't mention the server is asp.net website.